# VBA Color coding the entire column according to drop down list value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code in Sheet 1 VBA window. The excel sheet 1 in the workbook is with the drop down list in Column C. The 4 options of the drop down list are: Complete, Pending, Missed Deadline, and Workable. The drop down list is made using Sheet 2 and define name method. However, when I select the value for example, "Complete", the color for the whole row does not turn green. Where am I going wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'to make entire row green when job is workable
If Selection.Text = "Workable" Then
With ActiveCell
Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Select
         With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With
    End With

' to make entire row yellow when pending additonal information

ElseIf Selection.Text = "Pending" Then
With ActiveCell
Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Select

   With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With
    End With
'to make entire row red when job is not workable

ElseIf Selection.Text = "Missed Deadline" Then
With ActiveCell
Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Select
With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End With


'to make entire row light blue when job is complete

ElseIf Selection.Text = "Complete" Then
With ActiveCell
Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Select
With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

End With
End With

 MsgBox "AWESOME!YOU DID IT!"

 End If


End Sub
```

Please see code and kindly help. Thank you so much!

Comment: You just want to change the whole row? Use `EntireRow` and use `Target` rather than `Selection`.

Comment: @SJR No, the `Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Select` operator selects intended region.

Comment: @Eugene - I think there are better ways of doing that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on comment above

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'to make entire row green when job is workable
If Target.Text = "Workable" Then
    With Target.EntireRow
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5287936
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

    'etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Nabeela,

I would suggest you to switch to conditional formatting to complete this task instead of writing a macro.

You can add 4 styles, one for each color, and select formula-based condition, and add a formula (considering **N is the column with the status and 5 is the 1st row of the table**, replace with your values):

```
= $N5="Workable"
```

if you need OR condition you can use

```
= (($N5="Workable")+($N5="SomethingElse")>0)
```

if you need AND condition, use

```
= ($N5="Workable")*($N5="SomethingElse")
```

Then apply style to the whole table.

.

***Considering your comment***, look at this part:

```
With ActiveCell
    Range(Cells(.[........]
```

I would change this to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng as Excel.Range
'[...]  - your code here
With ActiveCell
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range( _
    Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), _
    Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1))
With rng.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
'[...and so on...]
```

Comment: Thanks @Eugene but neither are the other list values are working. It is not just with "complete". Also, thanks I will try to look into conditional formatting.

Comment: @NabeelaVan Are you sure your named range items contain no leading or trailing spaces? Do you get hits if you set a breakpoint at your If/ElseIfs?

Comment: Thanks for everything @Eugene but none of the macros are working because the workbook cannot detect them (some weird reason). Conditional formatting worked but I don't want it just for one cell based on text, I want it for the whole row. Also, I want to apply formatting based on variety of texts (not just one), I am not sure if conditional formatting is that advanced.

Comment: @NabeelaVan It is. You can use formula to check for a condition, when it returns TRUE, the style is applied. I'll explain how to.

Comment: @NabeelaVan edited answer to explain conditional formatting

Comment: @NabeelaVan Did it work? Did you understand how to use conditional formatting for a column?

Comment: Yes conditional formatting worked but it only worked for one cell. not the entire column. :(

Comment: @NabeelaVan , It works for the entire column as well, you just should configure it. Apply a rule to your range (not entire Excel column(!), but for your table's column), and write a formula for a first cell in the range, removing $ at row coordinates. Say, by default Excel sets $N$5, you change it to $N5. It works the same way as general Excel formulas. I'm sure this is the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim mClr As Long
 If Target.Column <> 3 Or Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Workable": mClr = 5287936
        Case "Pending": mClr = 65535
        Case "Missed Deadline": mClr = 255
        Case "Complete": mClr = 16247773
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select

    With Target.EntireRow.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = mClr
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

To make above code work if more than one cell changed at the same time (for example using copy and paste) and to reset the color to `xlNone` (white) if the cell value is not in the list:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim mClr As Long, Rng As Range, Cel As Range
 Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Columns(3))

 If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
     For Each Cel In Rng
        Select Case Cel.Value
            Case "Workable": mClr = 5287936
            Case "Pending": mClr = 65535
            Case "Missed Deadline": mClr = 255
            Case "Complete": mClr = 16247773
            Case Else: mClr = xlNone
        End Select

        With Cel.EntireRow.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = mClr
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
     Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But would you know why is the workbook not recognizing the code. When I open Alt+F8, this workbook doesn't show any Macro. So I am not able to run this.

Comment: this code will run automatically when any single cell  in column "C" changed. to copy it: right click on your sheet tab then choose `View Code` and paste this code there. and to make it run try to change any cell in column "C" to one of your values "Workable, Pending....."

Comment: Yes you're 100% right. It does work. It just mixes up color for first name on the list when done with a drop down list in Column C. But it is still pretty good. I am trying to make it work.

Comment: I hope you can make it work, good luck. I really don't know why it not work correctly. but I know that this code will not change the color if more than one cell changed at the same time, and it will not reset the color to no color (white) if the cell value is not in the list, but this can be easy to fix. I will edit my answer.